# Removing media controls and creating autoplay media

Tags: html, audio, controls, qualtrics

I am working on a research project that involves mp3 files being used during an experiment. These file will be played in Qualtrics. My lab is having trouble getting rid of the "user control" (pause/play, volume, mute, etc. options)

The code we have is in html

```
 <video class="qmedia" controls="true" height="260" preload="auto" 
width="320"><source src="https://vcubusiness.co1.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php? 
F=F_6feq8kJSWS8fMgZ" type="video/mp4" /><embed align="middle" 
autoplay="false" bgcolor="white" class="qmedia" controller="true" 
height="260" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
src="https://vcubusiness.co1.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_6feq8kJSWS8fMgZ" 
type="video/quicktime" width="320" /></video>
```

The final code should allow for autoplay but now allow users to adjust volume/pause/mute/download the mp3

Comment: See that [`controls="true"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_controls.asp) there? Well.

Comment: @Phiter , I am pretty sure it was set to false during our lab meeting and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Weird. It should. This is the option that disables the controls.

Comment: @Phiter we called Qualtrics and were told they would not write custom code for us and couldn't give a simple explanation to fixing this issue.. that's why I posted on here. I am going to e-mail the lab grad student and I will update you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. control=false isn't valid. If control is included it is true (control false is the absence of the control attribute). Unless you turn on autoplay, the respondent will have to right click to play since there aren't any controls. Also, your html5 isn't valid.

```
<video class="qmedia" height="260" width="320" preload="auto" >
<source src="https://vcubusiness.co1.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_6feq8kJSWS8fMgZ" 
type="video/mp4">
<embed align="middle" autoplay="false" bgcolor="white" class="qmedia" 
controller="true" height="260" 
pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" 
src="https://vcubusiness.co1.qualtrics.com/CP/File.php?F=F_6feq8kJSWS8fMgZ" 
type="video/quicktime" width="320">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will be following up with you once I hear a response from the grad student. I hope this works. I don't know what you mean by "your html5 isn't valid"

Comment: Self closing tags like `<source />` aren't valid html5. I took out the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

I only have this problem in chrome but what seemed to fix it is replacing the controls="false" with controls controlsList="nodownload" . I haven't solved how to disable users from right clicking to save the audio, though.